# jQuery line count code editor

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Im trying to accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WkVb9/

But instead of using a textarea, use an iframe with `designmode = 'on'`

http://jsfiddle.net/ysgEf/

It doesn't seem to work =/

Comment: keyup event isn't even firing for me.... get that working first ;)

Comment: Please include code in your question. This won't be a very useful question in the event that those URLs stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a look at this piece of code:](http://jsfiddle.net/ysgEf/5/)

```
var editable = $(document.getElementById('edit').contentWindow.document);

editable.attr('designMode', "on").keyup(function(){
    var length = $(this).find('body').children('br, p, div').length;

    if($(this).find('body').html().length && !length){
        length = 1;
    }

    $('#lc').text(length);
});
```

Here's the behavior of the various browsers tested:

- **Firefox 3.6**: `<br />` tags are appended to form the line breaks. At the start, there's no `<br />`, while after the first line break one is added before the current cursor position and one after
- **Chrome**: `<div>` are used to contain each line. `<br />` are used for empty lines. The first line is not wrapped
- **IE 8 Compatibility**: `<p>` are used to contain each line.

Lesson: Don't use `contentEditable` or `designMode`! The behavior is horribly inconsistent and quite useless for cases like this. Of course you can use hacks to get around this, but what happens when new browsers come out? You'd have to maintain this till the end of time!

Comment: what do you suggest I do rather than use contentEditable or designMode?

Comment: @David It depends on what you're doing. If you need WYSIWYG editors complete packages are already out there, like TinyMCE and others. If you need a plain text editor, then just use `textarea`! Alternatively, seriously consider using something like Markdown if you need WYSIWYG, because no matter which one you choose the resulting HTML is almost always rubbish

Comment: @Yi Jiang I am trying to create a basic WYSIWYG editor, basicly it's a textarea, with line numbers and if you are typing on an indented line, when you press enter, it is at the same indention level as the line above, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good start : http://jsfiddle.net/ysgEf/3/

It returns erroneous line numbers, but the code is working, which is better than nothing for now.

Know this : implementation is different across browsers! Finding the line numbers from the content of an iframe is not a straight forward task!

** **EDIT** **

Based on [Yi Jiang](#3801139)'s answer :

```
var editable = $(document.getElementById('edit').contentWindow.document)
    .find('body').css({'overflow':'auto', 'white-space':'nowrap'}).end();

editable.attr('designMode', "on").keyup(function(){
    var length = $(this).find('body')[0].childNodes.length;

    $('#lc').text(length);
});​
```

This also counts for text nodes, not returned by JQuery. And will also not wrap the lines around.

Comment: Please include code in your answers. Also this breaks easily: `a enter b enter` now go back up to the first line type anything and hit `enter`.